# How i can println the statuscode in display with a toast when the request is fail?

Tags: java, android, httpclient

Need to println `HttpResponse response` if the conexion is fail

```
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        return GET();

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Iniciando sesión...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

}




public String GET() {

        String url = "http://"+ippref+":8080/Activo/webresources/activo.entities.coreusuario/usuarios/" + usuario_ws + "/" +contrasenia_ws+ "";
        String result = "";
        BufferedReader inStream = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);

            response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            inStream = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            inStream.close();
            result = buffer.toString();

            respuesta_ws = Integer.valueOf(result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
```

Need printl the statuscode

Comment: Are you calling this code in an async task?

Comment: Yes i calling in a asynctask

Comment: your issue got resolved???

Comment: Yes, but i have other problem, when the status code is different to 200 the aplicattion be stoped, how i can resolved this problem?

Comment: I edit my code, it's my asynctask complet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for return status. If its value is not 200 then its a failure and toast it.

```
if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=200){
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Request failure!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is just what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

import android.widget.Toast

And you can change time of toast by changing `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`

Of course if you want to only show toast when http response is bad,then add the logic for checking the error cases and make toast there.
Hope this helps. :)